# English to Alien translator

Tags: code-golf, string

## Briefing

Aliens have settled on earth and strangely enough, their alphabet is the exact same as ours. Their language is also very similar to ours with some very distinct and easy to compute differences.

## Challenge

Take a string and output the alien's language equivalent. The translation works as such:

Swap all the vowels in the word with the corresponding:

```
  Vowel |   With
--------+--------
   a    |   obo
   e    |   unu
   i    |   ini
   o    |   api
   u    |   iki
```

<sub>You may also write another translator to translate Alien->English, this is optional however.</sub>

## Examples

```
Input: Shaun
Output: Shoboikin

Input: Java
Output: Jobovobo

Input: Hello, World!
Output: Hunullapi, Wapirld!
```

If the vowel is capitalized then you capitalize the first letter..

```
Input: Alan
Output: Obolobon

Input: Australia
Output: Oboikistroboliniobo
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply
- Must work for text that contains new lines
- You can either write a function, lambda, or full program

  Capingrobotikilobotiniapins apin wrinitining thunu runuvunursunu trobonslobotapir!

Comment: I'm not sure what *You may also write another translator to translate Alien->English* is supposed to mean. Can we write the reverse translator instead of the regular one?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it's not obvious to me that *also* carries this meaning here. Anyway, I'm not sure how this is a *rule* if it's not part of the actual task.

Comment: @Dennis You're being a bit punudobontinic, but I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: Why the requirement for newlines? In my opinion, this is unnecessary and doesn't add anything to the main point of the challenge.

Comment: Can the input contain any ASCII character or only a subset. E.g., will there ever be numbers in the input?

Comment: @Riley yes, there may be.

Comment: Will all strings be capitalized?

Answer (score 14):

## Haskell, <s>100</s> 91 bytes

```
(>>= \x->last$[x]:[y|(z:y)<-words"aobo eunu iini oapi uiki AObo EUnu IIni OApi UIki",z==x])
```

Comment: Hoboskunull surely

Answer (score 12):

## TI-Basic, 173 + 59 + 148 = 380 bytes

*Hopefully the aliens use TI-83/84 calculators ;)*

**Main Program, 173 bytes**

**BONUS:** Keep second or third line depending on whether your want a normal or reverse translator.

```
"("+Ans+")→Str1
"@a~obo@A~Obo@e~unu@E~Unu@i~ini@I~Ini@o~api@O~Api@u~iki@U~Iki@→Str2    <-- English to Alien
"@obo~a@Obo~A@unu~e@Unu~E@ini~i@Ini~I@api~o@Api~O@iki~u@Iki~U@→Str2    <-- Alien to English
For(I,2,length(Ans
If "@"=sub(Str2,I-1,1
Then
Str1+"~"+sub(Str2,I,inString(Str2,"@",I)-I
prgmQ
Ans→Str1
End
End
```

**Subprogram (`prgmQ`), 59 bytes:**

```
Ans→Str9
inString(Ans,"~
sub(Str9,Ans,length(Str9)-Ans+1→Str8
Str9
prgmR
Repeat Str9=Ans+Str8
Ans+Str8→Str9
prgmR
End
```

**Subprogram (`prgmR`), 148 bytes:**

```
Ans→Str0
inString(Ans,"~→Z
inString(Str0,"~",Ans+1→Y
inString(sub(Str0,1,Z-1),sub(Str0,Z+1,Ans-Z-1→X
sub(Str0,1,-1+inString(Str0,"~
If X
sub(Str0,1,X-1)+sub(Str0,Y+1,length(Str0)-Y)+sub(Str0,X+length(sub(Str0,Z+1,Y-Z-1)),Z-X-length(sub(Str0,Z+1,Y-Z-1
```

P.S. `~` represents token `0x81` and `@` represents token `0x7F`, learn more [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

P.P.S. Part of why these programs have a high byte count is because `sub(`, `inString(`, `length(`, and all lowercase letters are two bytes each...

Comment: I think you mixed up `prgmR` and `prgmQ` in your code headlines once?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that @ByteCommander :)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 56 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN

`alien.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%\w%"`"&$&|("A\x0fboE\x15nuI\x09niO\x01piU\x09ki"=~/\u$&\K.../,$&)%eg
```

Works as shown, but replace the `\xXX` escapes by the actual character to get the claimed score

Comment: +1 Upvoted just for the Alien avatar. Just kidding, the solution is nice, also.

Comment: Jesus christ.. Perl at its best, ladies and gents.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 20 bytes

```
žÀ.•₅%~≠#ùÛãú•3ôD™«‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7DDXqPGhY9ampVrXvUuUD58M7Dsw8vPrwLKGZ8eIvLo5ZFh1Y/alj4/7@SkpJHak5Ovo4CV3h@UU6KIlAAAA)

**Unuxplobonobotiniapin**

```
žÀ                    # the string "aeiouAEIOU"
  .•₅%~≠#ùÛãú•        # the string "obounuiniapiiki"
              3ô      # split in pieces of 3
                D™«   # concatenate with a title-case copy
                   ‡  # transliterate
```

Comment: Ini lapivunu gapilfining!

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring: Took me way too long to translate that in my head. I think I need a reverse translator :P

Comment: Go for it, shouldn't be too hard :P

Comment: Scary, I think it says I love golf.

Comment: I've changed my question which makes you answer invalid. This must work with new lines

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring: What about languages (like this) that can't take newlines in input? Would taking multiple inputs separated by a newline be an acceptable alternative? Like [this](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=fMK7xb5NRHXCq-KAmW9ib3VudWluacK4wrhpa2nigJkzw7RE4oSiwqvigKE&input=T25lIGxpbmUKVHdvIGxpbmVzClRoaXJkIHJvdw).

Answer (score 6):

## Python, <s>99</s> <s>95</s> 93 bytes

```
lambda s:"".join(("ouiaiOUIAI bnnpkbnnpk ouiiiouiii"+c)["aeiouAEIOU".find(c)::11] for c in s)
```

[On ideone.com...](http://ideone.com/QGS0cF)

Pretty simple. Just take the index we find each character at in the vowel list and use it to pull the three characters we need. If it's not found, `.find()` returns `-1` so just stick the current character on the end of the string. The spaces are necessary so any letter `"a"` doesn't include the added `c`. The translated vowels are grouped by letter order (the first letter of every translation, then the second, then the third).

Comment: Wow, nice creative approach. I'm impressed :)

Comment: You can remove the space in `["aeiouAEIOU".find(c)::11] for`

Answer (score 6):

## sed 89

```
s,a,&b\n,gi
s,i,&n\r,gi
s,o,&p\r,gi
s,u,&k\r,gi
s,e,&n\f,gi
y,aeouAEOU\n\r\f,ouaiOUAIoiu,
```

Comment: Does this work for input that contains newlines?

Comment: @Jordan It does. sed reads "one line at a time". So it will process everything up to the first newline, print that, print a newline, then start over if there is more text.

Comment: Ah, of course. 

Comment: @Jordan That wasn't a rule when I wrote this, but it ended up working anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP , 91 Bytes

```
<?=strtr($argv[1],[A=>Obo,E=>Unu,I=>Ini,O=>Api,U=>Iki,a=>obo,e=>unu,i=>ini,o=>api,u=>iki]);
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 129 bytes

```
lambda s:"".join([str,str.capitalize][ord(l)<91]({"a":"obo","e":"unu","i":"ini","o":"api","u":"iki"}.get(l.lower(),l))for l in s)
```

[See it running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/N3WxvZ)

Here's a more nicely formatted version:

```
lambda s: \
    "".join(
        [str, str.capitalize][ord(l) < 91](
            {"a":"obo", "e":"unu", "i":"ini", "o":"api", "u":"iki"}
            .get(l.lower(), l)
        )
    for l in s)
```

The most interesting parts are `{ ... }.get(l.lower(), l)` which tries to look up the letter stored in `l` converted to lower case in the dictionary and either returns the translated version (if found), or else the original letter,
and `[str, str.capitalize][ord(l) < 91]( ... )` which checks whether the original letter was a capital letter (ASCII code point lower than 91) and then either calls the `str()` function with the letter as argument (if it wasn't a capital letter, does nothing) or the `str.capitalize()` function (converts the first letter of the argument string to upper case).

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 215 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pt=
set s=
:l
if "%t%"=="" echo(%s%&exit/b
set c=%t:~0,1%
for %%a in (obo.a unu.e ini.i api.o iki.u Obo.A Unu.E Ini.I Api.O Iki.U)do if .%c%==%%~xa set c=%%~na
set s=%s%%c%
set t=%t:~1%
goto l
```

Takes input on STDIN. Processing character-by-character has the convenience of being case-sensitive.

Comment: Batch is just the worst tool for everything, isn't it? (Well, at least you beat TI-Basic :)

Nice seeing a codegolf in Batch, by the way!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 42 bytes

```
#sXw"aeiouAEIOU"+Jc"obounuiniapiiki"3mrd3J
```

A program that takes input on STDIN and prints the output.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23sXw%22aeiouAEIOU%22%2BJc%22obounuiniapiiki%223mrd3J&input=Shaun%0AJava%0AHello%2C+World%21%0AAlan%0AAustralia&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
#sXw"aeiouAEIOU"+Jc"obounuiniapiiki"3mrd3J  Program.
#                                           Loop until error statement:
   w                                         Get w, the next line of the input
                   "obounuiniapiiki"         Yield string literal "obounuiniapiiki"
                  c                 3        Split that into groups of three characters
                 J                           Assign that to J and yield J
                                     mrd3J   Map title case over J
                +                            Merge the lower and title groups
    "aeiouAEIOU"                             Yield string literal "aeiouAEIOU"
  X                                          Translate w from that to the three-character
                                             groups
 s                                           Concatenate that
                                             Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 167 bytes

I really didn't want to break my habit of always doing main functions when coding C, but this is substantially shorter than the version with a main and this way I got another letter to spell what I wanted!

### Golfed

```
a;l;i;e(char*n){for(;i=*n++;l=i>90,i-=32*l,a=!(i-65)+2*!(i-69)+3*!(i-73)+4*!(i-79)+5*!(i-85),printf(a?"%c%c%c":"%c",(a?"HOUIAI"[a]:i)+l*32,"ibnnpk"[a],"!ouiii"[a]));}
```

### Commented

```
a;l;i;
e(char*n)
{
    for(;
        i = *n++;  /* Get char and advance */
        l = i>90,  /* Is lowercase? */
        i -= 32*l, /* Make uppercase */

        /* Is 1,2,3,4,5 depeding on the vowel and 0 for no vowel */
        a = !(i-65) + 2*!(i-69) + 3*!(i-73) + 4*!(i-79) + 5*!(i-85),

        printf(a?"%c%c%c":"%c",        /* Print 1 or 3 chars? */
               (a?"HOUIAI"[a]:i)+l*32, /* Print appropriate char+case */
                  "ibnnpk"[a],            /* Print appropriate char */
                  "!ouiii"[a]));          /* Print appropriate char */
}
```

There is something special about C and how horrible you can be with pointers and such.

Comment: [151 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcmxCsIwFIXh3adoLwhJmkJRFw1ROgiti4OIgzhcY9WLMS01LYL47NU6yll@vmPiizFdZ65Yi1ZDkC7z9Rak8AqVVaQK9rscf53LminSwkWRqmpy/sxgaPpBNBEhSoYLyNbbPM1hj4cZ8ciK8UgCHZ2rbr1JCMuGiGDvNblT8WStpFiPR8JyidovfNzOkgPnVtN8mqh3d0dyjL8GBYPNFRsHXFWNfzD4Ro8rbPHfssLaUga7sransLd39wE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat I'd say post your answer on its own. It's diverged enough to deserve its own answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>150 141 136</s> 134 bytes

```c
a;i;e(char*n){for(char*v=" AEIOUIAI",*t;i=*n++;printf(&a))t=index(v,i-i/96*32),a=t?t-v:0,a=a?v[a+3]|L" 潢畮楮楰楫"[a]<<8|i&32:i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ROtM6VSM5I7FIK0@zOi2/CMIus1VScHT19A/1dPRU0tEqsc601crT1rYuKMrMK0nTUEvU1CyxzcxLSa3QKNPJ1M3UtzTTMjbS1Em0LbEv0S2zMgCyEu3LohO1jWNrfJQUnu1d9HzqumdLgWjDs6WrlaITY21sLGoy1YyNrDKta//nJmbmaWhWc6VqKAVnJJbmKWlaF5SWFGsoARkgQa/EskR0MY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEV0ScecRAxDHEuLS4oSczJBJnHV/gcA)

Based on the answer by @algmyr and -8 thanks to @ASCII-only

Less golfed version

```c
a;i;
e(char*n){
  for(char*v=" AEIOUIAI",*t;i=*n++;printf(&a))
    t=index(v,i-i/96*32),
    a=t?t-v:0,
    a=a?v[a+3]|L" 潢畮楮楰楫"[a]<<8|i&32:i;
}
```

Comment: 149? `a;l;i;e(char*n){for(char*v=" AEIOU",*t;i=*n++;printf("%c%c%c"+4*!a,(a?" OUIAI"[a]:i)|i&32," bnnpk"[a]," ouiii"[t=index(v,i-32*l),a=t?t-v:0]))l=i>96;}`

Comment: maybe also 149: `a;l;i;e(char*n){for(char*v="AEIOU",*t;i=*n++;printf("%c%c%c"+4*!a,(a?" OUIAI"[a]:i)|i&32," bnnpk"[a]," ouiii"[t=index(v,i&95),a=t&&t-v<5?t-v+1:0]));}`

Comment: 144: `a;l;i;e(char*n){for(char*v=" AEIOU",*t;i=*n++;)printf("%c%c%c"+4*!a,a?" OUIAI"[a]|i&32:i," bnnpk"[a]," ouiii"[t=index(v,i-i/96*32),a=t?t-v:0]);}`

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 60 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
[A-Z]
»$&
T`L`l
i
ini
u
iki
e
unu
a
·b·
o
api
·
o
T`»l`_L`».
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=W0EtWl0KwrskJgpUYExgbAppCmluaQp1CmlraQplCnVudQphCsK3YsK3Cm8KYXBpCsK3Cm8KVGDCu2xgX0xgwrsu&input=SGVsbG8sIEF1c3RyYWxpYSE)

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>94</s> <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,c=>"OUIAIouiai"[n="AEIOUaeiou".search(c)]+"bnnpk"[n%=5]+"ouiii"[n])
```

*Saved 1 byte thanks to edc65*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to Neil*

#### Demo

```js
let f =
s=>s.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,c=>"OUIAIouiai"[n="AEIOUaeiou".search(c)]+"bnnpk"[n%=5]+"ouiii"[n])

function translate() {
  document.getElementById("o").value = f(document.getElementById("i").value);
}
translate();
```

```html
<input id="i" size=80 oninput="translate()" value="Hello, World!"><br><input id="o" size=80 disabled>
```

Comment: To check the return value of `.indexOf` and `.search` use `~` instead of `<0`

Comment: I looked to see what would happen if you only replaced vowels, and I originally got `s=>s.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,c=>"ouiaiOUIAI"[n="aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c)]+"bnnpk"[n%=5]+"ouiii"[n])` which is still 93 bytes. But since `c` is now known to be a vowel you can now use `search` instead of `indexOf` to save a byte!

Comment: @Neil - Nice! I tried both, actually, but didn't think about combining them.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>133</strike> 121 bytes

```cs
s=>{int i;return string.Concat(s.Select(c=>(i ="AIUEOaiueo".IndexOf(c))>-1?"OboIniIkiUnuApioboiniikiunuapi".Substring(i*3,3):c+""));}
```

## Edit (thanks to `milk`)

thank you :) I actually know this overload but somehow completely forgot it when writing this..

```cs
s=>string.Concat(s.Select((c,i)=>(i="AIUEOaiueo".IndexOf(c))>-1?"OboIniIkiUnuApioboiniikiunuapi".Substring(i*3,3):c+""));
```

Comment: You can use the `Select(char, int)` overload so you don't need to declare `i` and can put it all in one line. `s=>string.Concat(s.Select((c,i)=>(i="AIUEOaiueo".IndexOf(c))>-1?"OboIniIkiUnuApioboiniikiunuapi".Substring(i*3,3):c+""));`

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8, 172 bytes

```
String f(String s){String v="AEIOUaeiou",r="OboUnuIniApiIkiobounuiniapiiki",o="";for(char c:s.toCharArray()){int n=v.indexOf(c);o+=n>-1?r.substring(n*3,n*3+3):c;}return o;}
```

ungolfed:

```
String f(String s){
    String v="AEIOUaeiou",r="OboUnuIniApiIkiobounuiniapiiki",o="";
    for(char c:s.toCharArray()){
        int n=v.indexOf(c);
        o+=n>-1?r.substring(n*3,n*3+3):c;
    }
    return o;
}
```

And Alien back to English (171 bytes):

```
String g(String s){String[] v="AEIOUaeiou".split(""),r="Obo Unu Ini Api Iki obo unu ini api iki".split(" ");for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++)s=s.replaceAll(r[i],v[i]);return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
String g(String s){
    String[] v="AEIOUaeiou".split(""),r="Obo Unu Ini Api Iki obo unu ini api iki".split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++)s=s.replaceAll(r[i],v[i]);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 75 bytes

String to be translated is in the variable `s`.

```
string map {A Obo a obo E Unu e unu I Ini i ini O Api o api U Iki u iki} $s
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 128 bytes

```
#~StringReplace~{"a"->"obo","A"->"Obo","e"->"unu","E"->"Unu","i"->"ini","I"->"Ini","o"->"api","O"->"Api","u"->"iki","U"->"Iki"}&
```

Not sure whether a shorter program can be obtained by using `IgnoreCase->True` together with a case check.

Answer (score 2):

**C, <s>207</s> 202 bytes** (thanks to Cyoce)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define r(c,t) case c:printf(t);continue;
int main(){int c;while(~(c=getchar())){switch(c){r('a',"obo")r('e',"unu")r('i',"ini")r('o',"api")r('u',"iki")default:putchar(c);}}return 0;}
```

1) I hate to omit type before any kind of declarations

2) I don't really like to put unusable code (without main() function)

**Usage:**

```
c89 cg.c -o cg; echo "Testing" | ./cg
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @MartinEnder, that's unexpected... but thank you :)

Comment: `(c=getchar())!= EOF` can become `~(c=getchar())`

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcjRDoIgGIbhu1HYciMT8Y@x1o20sR81ttKGeKRx64R08uz9PqxGxBiNfGs7EaTbMDsiA0E19h6f2hFK5cfZyQ@kQEqNwj1c6hPu6lBhVeryluyzNjtn1@QjmKspWmCdECLXmbEG/h/whqcSLXDojk/UAGnIb4z3dfFOv6z@AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

**C 178 bytes**

```
char*p[256],*a="obo\0unu\0ini\0api\0iki\0Obo\0Unu\0Ini\0Api\0Iki",*b="aeiouAEIOU";main(c){for(c=0;b[c];++c)p[b[c]]=a+4*c;for(;(c=getchar())>0;)p[c]?printf("%s",p[c]):putchar(c);}
```

Comment: [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY29CsIwFEbfJYMkTYUi6mAopYNDQeggnZoM6aU/l2ISSjOJvnpMXM43HDgfHGeAECDPXH@6XFWeDeWD6BGtr@9N2xHx0mgoe092o2LoQQnm@ricK1USO1hZeONlgQZloV0ErhFtEl0STRJ1Es2KhJ8zEP/Wl0I5jzsseqOMxeqGZp@oixdVwu0ATHxCeC7amx8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat &c can be ok if it save number as byte1 byte2 byte3... For example 255  in memory as ff 00 00 00 but if there is the other endian for 255 we have 00 00 00 ff and print the void string ...

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>163</s> <s>162</s> 159 bytes

```c
char*t="aeiou";n,k;q(char*x){for(;*x;n<0||(*x=t[n>1?n%2?0:2:n+3])&&k>90||(*x-=32),printf("%c%.2s",*x++,n<0?"":&"bonunipiki"[2*n]))n=strchr(t,tolower(k=*x))-t;}
```

Comment: putting `char*t="aeiou";` into for loop saves 1 byte

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc5Bj4IwFATgO79CX0LSluJiPS21cvXuYQ/GQ6moDewr1hKbGH87C@5tkvmSGZNfjRlH5K28E3PTnkX6ujj/n4MC3Vg3gGRR9t5iuBBITboSD@AsZpnCbVGxWIYj7tYVpqIqSlFitjnl38VXyzaCzwKghNrhgLa3rYVMMKQUlcVzE0ngwXXu2XjSqmmd5kG@x19tkdBXMt9Y6ONJweGmBwSZ3ImmMumH8CAAU/qIehb7puscX/w4352XH1lP/Xv8Aw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 2.2 196 bytes

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

#### Golfed

```
var r = ["a":"obo","e":"unu","i":"ini","o":"api","u":"iki"];var q={(s:String) in var o = "";for var i in s.lowercaseString.characters{o += r[String(i)] != nil ? r[String(i)]!:String(i)};print(o);}
```

#### unGolfed

```
var r = ["a":"obo","e":"unu","i":"ini","o":"api","u":"iki"]
var q={(s:String) in
    var o = ""
    for var i in s.lowercaseString.characters {
        o += r[String(i)] != nil ? r[String(i)]!:String(i)
    }
    print(o)
}
```

Comment: Are the spaces in `var r = [` necessary?

Comment: Yeah in the playgrounds app if you don't put a space in between an assignment it give you an error and tells you to add spaces. Swift is probably one of the worst languages to golf with but I thought it would be fun to try.

Comment: And it was interesting it didn't give me that error when I was assigning a variable to a closure. Hence the shrugging man

Comment: yeah I noticed that too. That's why I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>84</s>  82 bytes

```perl6
{my%o=<a obo e unu i ini o api u iki>;S:i:g[<{%o.keys}>]=%o{$/.lc}.samecase($/~'a')}
```

```perl6
{my%o=<a obo e unu i ini o api u iki>;S:i:g[<[aeiou]>]=%o{$/.lc}.samecase($/~'a')}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  # create the mapping
  my %v = <a obo e unu i ini o api u iki>;

  # replace vowels in ｢$_｣
  S
    :ignorecase
    :global
  [
    <[aeiou]>
  ]

  = # replace them with:

  %v{ $/.lc }
  # change it to be the same case as what was matched, and a lowercase letter
  .samecase( $/ ~ 'a' )
}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
my &english-to-alien = {my%o=<a obo e unu i ini o api u iki>;S:i:g[<[aeiou]>]=%o{$/.lc}.samecase($/~'a')}

say english-to-alien 'Australia'; # Oboikistroboliniobo
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <strike>102</strike> <strike>93</strike> <strike>91</strike> <strike>88</strike> 78 bytes

```
gsub(/[#{b='aeiouAEIOU'}]/){'obounuiniapiikiOboUnuIniApiIki'[b.index($&)*3,3]}
```

*Explanation:*

Execute the line like `ruby -pe "gsub(/[#{b='aeiouAEIOU'}]/){'obounuiniapiikiOboUnuIniApiIki'[b.index($&)*3,3]}"`, next up type, for example, `Australia` it should output: `Oboikistroboliniobo`.

It's pretty straightforward, replace all vowels with a substring based on the index of the to-be replaced vowel in (b), times 3 and the next 3 characters in the translation string.

Comment: I suspect the leading and trailing quotation marks (and internal escapes if the input has quotation marks) in the output might disqualify this. Anyway, you can save two bytes by moving the assignment of `b` into the Regexp (`/[#{b=...}/`).

Comment: I think the space `p $*` is unnecessary

Comment: Use the `-p` flag to save additional bytes. `ruby -pe 'gsub(/[#{b="aeiouAEIOU"}]/){"obounuiniapiikiOboUnuIniApiIki"[b.index($&)*3,3]}'`

Comment: I count 78 + 2 (`-pe`).  How do you get 71?

Comment: @NotthatCharles do the characters needed for execution really matter in this case? I just didn't count them.

Comment: @Biketire See the second bullet in the "Special Invocations" section in this [meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/13950).  Looks like this is a `+1` case.  But how did you get 71 to begin with?  The number of bytes in the answer look like 78 to me.

Comment: @NotthatCharles turns out I can't count.. I fixed it :)

Comment: @Biketire no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

### C - 192 bytes

(newlines added for clarity)

```c
int c,j,b;main(){
char*f[]={"bo","nu","ni","pi","ki",""},
s[]={14,16,0,-14,-12};
while(c=getchar()){for(b=j=0;j<10;++j)
{if(c=="aeiouAEIOU"[j]){c+=s[j%=5];b=1;break;}}
printf("%c%s",c,f[b?j:5]);}}
```

Just lookup tables and a boolean switch.

Lookup each letter in table (string) of vowels; if found, then modify it according to the rule in table `s`. Print each character followed by a string: if a vowel was found, print the character modified by the value in `s` followed by the rest of the syllable stored in table `f`; if a vowel was not found, print the original character and an empty string.

Comment: [145 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9LJ8k6NzEzTyNZszotv0jDuk4j2TY9tSQ5I7FIQ1PTuqAoM68kTUNJNVm1WEknWUfNR@nZ3kXPp657thSINjxbulopOsne1CorVlMTpD/JNsvWwDrLxtBATQPISdZVSkzNzC91dPX0D1WKBqqqqVHUSNa2VfLxszMwAoqo2prG6poZAa3S1s7StK79/98jNScnX0chPL8oJ0URAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, <s>201</s> <s>197</s> 195 bytes

```
Ans+" →Str1:"AEIOUaeiou→Str2:"OUIAIouiai→Str3:"bonunipiki→Str4:1→X:While X<length(Str1:inString(Str2,sub(Str1,X,1→A:5fPart(.2A→B:If A:sub(Str1,1,X-1)+sub(Str3,A,1)+sub(Str4,2B-1,2)+sub(Str1,X+1,length(Str1)-X→Str1:X+1+2(A>0→X:End:sub(Str1,1,length(Str1)-1
```

To think that I'd find another TI-BASIC answer here!

Anyway, the input is an English string in `Ans`.
The output is the translated string.

**Examples:**

```
"HE
HE
prgmCDGF1A
HUnu
"Hello
Hello
prgmCDGF1A
Hunullapi
```

**Explanation:**
(Newlines added for readability.  Multiple lines from the same line will be denoted with a `:` in the following code block.)

```
Ans+" →Str1                     ;append a space to the input string and store the result
                                ; in "Str1"
"AEIOUaeiou→Str2                ;store the upper- and lowercase vowels in "Str2"
"OUIAIouiai→Str3                ;store the beginning letter of each corresponding translated
                                ; vowel in "Str3"
"bonunipiki→Str4                ;store the remaining letters of each translated vowel
                                ; in "Str4"
1→X                             ;store 1 in "X"
While X<length(Str1             ;loop until all English letters have been checked
inString(Str2,sub(Str1,X,1→A    ;get the current letter and store its index in "Str2"
                                ; into "A"
5fPart(.2A→B                    ;get which translated vowel end should be used
                                ; B ranges from 1 to 5
If A                            ;if the current letter is a vowel
sub(Str1,1,X-1)                 ;extract the substring of the input before the
                                ; current letter
: +sub(Str3,A,1)                ;append the translated vowel start
: +sub(Str4,2B-1,2)             ;append the translated vowel end
: +sub(Str1,X+1,length(Str1)-X  ;append the remaining substring of the input
: →Str1                         ;store the result of these concatenations into "Str1"
X+1+2(A>0→X                     ;check if A>0 (if the current letter was a vowel)
                                ; if true, increment "X" by three
                                ; if false, increment "X" by one
End
sub(Str1,1,length(Str1)-1       ;remove the trailing space and store the result in "Ans"
                                ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

---

**Notes:**

- TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.
- Lowercase letters in TI-BASIC are two bytes each.